# Tensorflow 2.1 showing weird behaviour while training and evaluating on discriminator during GAN training

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am training a GAN on my custom image dataset. I am facing a weird issue with tensorflow (2.1) discriminator training process. When i call evaluate and train methods, the metric results produced are different. Can anyone please let me know why there is huge difference. I assume model.evaluate result as correct result.

```
discriminator.train_on_batch(generated_images, zeros)
```

outputs: loss:0.3693015, accuracy:1.0

```
discriminator.evaluate(generated_images, zeros)
```

outputs: loss: 0.9416157603263855, accuracy:0.0

```
discriminator.predict(generated_images)

outputs: array([[0.9242853 ],
           [0.9242752 ],
           [0.92427176],
           [0.92424864],
           [0.9242797 ],
           [0.9242201 ],
           [0.9242201 ],
           [0.92427665],
           [0.9242958 ],
           [0.9242941 ],
           [0.9243046 ],
           [0.9242498 ],
           [0.92428845],
           [0.92429376],
           [0.9242994 ],
           [0.92427266],
           [0.9242796 ],
           [0.92427236],
           [0.924284  ],
           [0.9242925 ]], dtype=float32)
```

Since my true label is all zeros so i believe probability of 0.9** should be classified as label 1 and hence accuracy should be 0% which is correctly being returned by model.evaluate() method but my training is going all wrong because fit and train_on_batch method return accuracy 100% and loss close to 0.

Below is my GAN compilation code -

```
ones = np.ones(batch_size)
zeros = np.zeros(batch_size)
    
generator = build_generator(dims=latent_dim)
print("-------- Generator Summary --------")
generator.summary()
    
Build & compile discriminator model
discriminator = build_discriminator (image_size=image_size)
discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(0.0002, 0.5), metrics=['accuracy'])
print("\n\n-------- Discriminator Summary --------")
discriminator.summary()
    
#Build & compile GAN (combined) model
gan = build_gan(generator, discriminator, dims=latent_dim)
gan.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(0.0002, 0.5), metrics=['accuracy'])
    
print("\n\n-------- GAN Summary --------")
gan.summary()
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks